# Silverlight: Alternative to using a DataContextProxy?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, memory-leaks

We have been using the DataContextProxy concept based on (or exactly) as described in [Dan Wahlin's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx).  Functionally This has worked fine for our purposes.  However, after doing extensive memory profiling, and after discovering similar reports online (link below), it seems that this approach leaks memory as a result of a problem/bug with UserControl.Resources.

Has anyone found a decent alternative to the DataContextProxy approach?

[Connect Report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/649246/usercontrol-resources-memory-leak-silverlight-4-0-60129-0), which says the problem has been fixed in SL 5.  I am going to try to post a repro solution for SL4.

Comment: I'm glad I am not the only developer that has noticed this!  See my previous post on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091636/silverlight-4-memory-leaks

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with something very close to the DataContextProxy but instead of the binding being created in the Loaded event of the class, the declaration in the XAML binds back to the class. Seems to work exactly the same except it doesn't leak. 
Would love someone else to verify this.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DataContextProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" ViewModel="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The class

```
namespace Silverlight.Infrastructure
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Refactored to not leak. Set binding on ViewModel propery to DataContext of page, in Resources of page
   /// Binding in XAML on declaration of DataContextProxy
   /// Usage: <shared:DataContextProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" ViewModel="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   /// </summary>
   /// <remarks></remarks>
   public class DataContextProxy : DependencyObject
   {
      public static DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof (object), typeof (DataContextProxy), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

      public object ViewModel
      {
         get { return (object)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
         set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
      }
   }
}
```

usage:

```
DataToBindTo="{Binding ViewModel.DataToBindTo, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}"
```

Changed the binding to ElementName as it seemed to work better on child views that didn't get a viewmodel until after the binding had been initially resolved.

Comment: I have found that with Silverlght 5's Ancestor binding, DataContextProxy is no longer needed. :)

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you so much Stephen. Moving to SL5 is not an option for me at this point because of some old version dependencies. This is such a clean and straightforward solution. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this](http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/) SL implementation of a relative source binding.  Caliburn Micro also has a way to solve this problem by Action bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of memory leaks problems, but as Silverlight 4 introduced `ElementName` in bindings, it mostly eliminates the need for a `DataContextProxy`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Languages, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
```

More explanations [here](http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/silverlight-datacontextproxy-no-longer-necessary/).

Comment: Unfortunately `ElementName` binding doesn't work inside `DataGrids`.

Comment: Is it `DataGrid`'s implementation fault that could be corrected or is happening in some other item containers? It would be useful to understand the underlying technical reason why `ElementName` fails.

Comment: Hi @Mart sorry for getting back to you this late. I think the datagrid column collection is just a property, it's not in the logical/visual tree, and ElementName binding uses the logial tree I believe.