# Silverlight memory issue

Tags: c#, silverlight

We have a Silverlight 5 application that runs in the browser. The application can have many layouts that the user can create. These layouts can contain grids, charts and Map controls.
Once user opens a layout, out application keeps the data for that layout even if the user goes of the layout and open another one. This was intended to make it faster to come back to an already opened layout.

The issue we are facing now that over time, the browser (IE10, IE11) reaches 1GB in size which results in out of memory exception and consequently our application starts to fall over and gets exceptions on service calls.

Now the question is:
What is the best way to manage memory in a silverlight application given that the user can open a number of layouts concurrently which can take a substantial amount of memory.

I hope I have explained my scenario well. please any suggestion would be appreciated.

Regards,

Nasir

Comment: Check out these links:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/f44899a5-0cd9-47fd-bea4-454a7f24ee49/unmanaged-memory-leak-in-silverlights-navigation-frame-page?forum=silverlightperf
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436176/silverlight-clear-unused-memory-on-navigating-to-another-page

Comment: Thanks, I have already seen those links but I don't see the question answered with an accepted answer. We are using silverlight 5 b the way.

Comment: Have you ran a memory profiler like redgate against it to help identify exactly where your troubles are? We did that recently and found leaks not previously considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you are going to need to use a memory profiler to determine exactly what is going on.  It is highly unlikely that a few layout pages are eating up 1 gb of memory.  If I were debugging this, I would start by NOT saving the layout pages, and see if the memory usage changes.

But there is no way to know where the memory is going without doing some profiling.